# Recommendations for hard-copy dictionary for middle schoolers

Tags: educación

I am looking for recommendations on dictionaries suitable for English language learners (immigrants) in middle school. English-Spanish and Spanish-English dictionaries will be needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for learning materials are specifically off-topic here at Spanish Language, and recommendations are off-topic for pretty much the entire SE network. You might try Amazon or other book-rating services for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

When my wife came to Spain she got herself a [Webster's New World Pocket Spanish Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=Webster%27s+New+World+Pocket+Spanish+Dictionary.&oq=Webster%27s+New+World+Pocket+Spanish+Dictionary.&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.949j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8).

It was affordable, small enough to be carried in a bag and complete. She is a teacher (worked as a teacher in USA and as an English teacher in Spain), so she new what she was looking for when she got hers.